# iOS 8 Custom Cell: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key description.'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath, I have the following:

```
NSString *myIdentifier =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ExpandableCell"];

ExpandableTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
```

This worked completely fine on iOS 7, but now it's crashing on iOS 8 with the following error:

```
[<ExpandableTableViewCell 0x157d8980> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key description.'
```

I've already looked at the most common issue which was that the outlets were linked to the File Owner, but my xib doesn't have that anymore (see attached):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting. So I guess you can't have another variable named 'description'. My header file was complaining that I couldn't do so, instead I created/renamed that property to 'desc' and everything seems to work as usual.

This doesn't seem like it was a probably prior to iOS 8.

Comment: `description` has been a method of NSObject since, like, the Stone Age.  How the box malfunctions if you abuse it has probably changed once or twice, but defining a property named `description` has always been an error.

Comment: This seems to be the issue if the app was working on iOS 7. Had accidentally named one of the variables `description` and it was messing it up.

Comment: this also happened to me. there was a property with description as its name and when I migrated to Xcode 6, the crash started to happen. In older versions, it was okay but maybe they did something that restricts usage of description as variable/property name now. I'm not an expert with iOS changes but it's wise to just use another name.

Answer (score 4):

Right. Recall that NSObject has a method 'description'. If you were to use description as a property in core data, it would attempt to create accessor methods (i.e. get, set) and therefore conflict with NSObject method.